# woocommerce - Remove “view Order" Button in my Account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

What is the correct way to hide only the view Button at My account/orders

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without seeing any code, but assuming you are using WooCommerce out of the box, this CSS rule should work for you:

```
td.woocommerce-orders-table__cell.woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-actions, th.woocommerce-orders-table__header.woocommerce-orders-table__header-order-actions {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, the code worked, but the view button as well as the invoice (Plugin for invoice) button is no longer visible. However, I would like only the view. Button is no longer visible.  That is the selector from the view Button            .woocommerce-MyAccount-orders tbody .view

Comment: thanks a lot i got it working now because of your answer

I used the following code:

/* button */
.woocommerce-MyAccount-orders tbody .view{
 display:none !important;
}

and I have changed bit the width for the better look

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blanking out the entire table cell where other link buttons may exist for invoices, etc. just take out the View button:

```
.woocommerce-button button view {
    display: none;
}
```